# Trying to call mkl routines while having initialized a matlab compiled shared dll

Tags: matlab, initialization

I have a project that calls a MATLAB (v7.0.4) Compiler-generated dll. The same project also calls some MKL Intel Fortran 2011 routines. 
The program complains that there are conflicting mkl libraries that attempt to get initialized because MATLAB has its own (older in this case) mkl libraries when I am also directly using some MKL routines from a more recent MKL library. The exact message is “OMP abort: initializing libguide40.lib but found libiomp5md.dll already initialized.” The INTEL suggested less than ideal fix is the set environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK = TRUE to overcome this case. I would like a more proper solution.

Naturally this problem only arises when the project calls the MKL routines while the Matlab compiled dll has already been initialized but not terminated yet (using Initialize and Terminate). The mkl routines call would work fine if I call beforehand the Terminate on the Matlab comipled dll.
However, the calls to Matlab compiled dll and MKL are intertwined and the matlab compiled dll doesn’t accept the usage of Initialize and Terminate more than once in the application, so I am unable to unload the matlab dll to avoid having conflicting mkl libraries when calling the MKL routines to then re-load the dll afterwards for more matlab dll calls.
If I use more than once the matlab compiled dll’s interface methods mclInitializeApplication and mclTerminateApplication the program will crash, and if I use more than once Initialize and Terminate the program will just hang indefinitely on the Initialize call. I can't use mclInhibitShutdown() as this will not terminate the dll while I need to do so to be able to call the MKL routines without conflicting mkl libraries.

Is there a way to unload and reload the Matlab compiled dll repeatedly in the same application to avoid this conflicting mkl libraries?? I have added another dll ‘link’ between my project and the Matlab compiled dll but that didn't solve it either. So my project calls a 'link' dll which in turn calls the Matlab compiled dll, I tried terminating the Matlab compiled dll and then freeing the ‘link’ dll but for some reason I would still be unable to reload the Matlab compiled dll.

Any suggestions on how to handle this? I am new at this so I might not be very accurate in my description.

Thanks,
Samer.

Comment: If the Intel suggested fix works, I can't understand why you don't adopt it.  What are the characteristics of the more 'proper' solution you seek that the Intel suggestion lacks ?

Answer (score 0):

Both `libguide40.dll` and `libiomp5md.dll` are in fact run-time libraries for OpenMP (later is newer and more advanced). Using `KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK = TRUE` is not recommended because it may cause performance problems and even hangs. There is only one possible solutions I can think of:

Switch to newer version of MATLAB. Later versions of MATLAB use `libiomp5md.dll` so your application can link with `libiomp5md.dll` that comes with MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks Romeo, it looks like there is no other way of doing it. I am unable to use later MATLAB versions for this application for other reasons, so I will have to avoid using MATLAB all together on this one!

Comment: Also, you can try to force your application to use old version of OpenMP run-time library that comes with MATLAB.